# Using Release Manager to kick off tests in MTM.

Tags: powershell, mtm, tcm

I am having an issue with kicking off test cases in Microsoft Test Manager from a script kicked off in Microsoft Release Manager. I can duplicate the issue when just running this command from powershell or command line. Here is the script:

`C:\CODE\TCM\TCM.exe run /create /title:"Chads Example Test Case (Run from PowerShell)" /planid:31 /suiteid:2743 /configid:67 /settingsname:"DevWelisRemoteExecution" /testenvironment:"STAR_Regression" /collection:"http://tfssrv64:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /teamproject:QA /builddir:"\\tfssrv64\Builds" /include`

Running this script returns a test run ID with no errors. I can immediately look in MTM and see the test run has started. It has a state of "pending". It eventually (some 20 minutes later) fails with the error "The test automation associated with the following test case could not be found: [48667]. Run the test case again using a build that contains the binary with the test automation.".

Facts: I can run the same test successfully, with a successful completion, from Microsoft Test Manager. (using the same settings specified in the script) Here are screen shots of the test runs from MTM.

1. Here is the MTM log of the successful test run.
   [The log of the successful test run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEFZU.png)

Here is the same screen from the failed test run.

2. Here is the MTM log of the failed test run. Same test, ran from the above script.
   [The log of the failed test run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efk5E.png)

Both test runs are using the same build number. Both test runs use the same test settings and configuration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.....